# ASP.NET web site: Delay in page load

Tags: asp.net, performance, deployment

I have a web application developed in ASP.NET 2.0, deployed in a data center. The application is a media portal with CMS.

The application is hosted in Windows Server 2008 and the database is SQL Server 2005 in Windows 2003 Server.

I have home page with numerous links to sub pages or articles. When I click on any of the links in home page, it will load the content of the page in article.aspx. My problem is with the delay of rendering the article.aspx page.

The status bar shows the progress of loading the new page. But the actual page render happens after few more seconds (20-30) after showing progress of page loads completes ie. after completing the progress bar in the status bar of my browser, the browser retains to show the current page and its showing a "Done" message in the left side if status bar. After 20- 30 seconds then the browser renders the desired page (article.aspx)

The speed was good initially and the performance came down almost after an year of hosting. What is happening here? Do I need to check anything with IIS or DB?

Comment: Do you see this delay every time the page is accessed or only after the application and/or IIS is restarted?

Comment: Can you give us more information about what is happening in the page. both server side and client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check either it is database or code.

I agree with robert and suspect this is due to database. you can use sql profiler to find out what is going wrong.

If database is not the culprit then You have to use some kind of profiling tools to check what is going wrong.

As frogbot suggested asp.net trace is one way.

you can also use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/),[YSLOW](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/),[Pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) as firfox plugin to help you.

[RedGate's Ant Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) is very good but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Ajax or other javascript code that render content in client-side runtime? This will happen hafter the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your page loads are going to the database for data,  maybe your populating a grid and some drop downs for instance.  As the data has increased in the DB over time the queries have grown progressively longer to run and your page load has slowed as a result.

Perhaps the host now hosts more sites and more databases on the same servers which has also impacted the site.

Possibly just 1 bad piece of SQL taking 20-30 seconds to complete.

Network issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable tracing to see what's wrong. Check the articles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398859.aspx). If you find it is the database issue use SQL Server Profiler.